# ExtJS Highcharts Re-Charting Load Mask Hangs

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts, highcharts, rally

In my code snippet, a Deferred/Promise returns a configured Highchart Chart object named **myChart** .  First time through, my chart is added to a container and everything renders perfectly.  However, on subsequent calls where my logic performs a removeAll to refresh the container, my chart renders gray-out with loadMask ("Loading ...") spinning perpetually.

I've investigated the myChart object data for variance and it seems to be stable.  I've even attempted to render far more simplified chart objects and in every case the subsequent renderings hang with the loadMask spinning.

Any thoughts on why it might be hanging on all the subsequent calls??

I've read in somewhat-related threads that buffering can be an issue, but I don't think that applies since I am using arrays and using store objects to load the data into the chart.

Thanks in advance for any hints or pointers!

```
// Set chart data
that._setChartData().then({

    success: function( myChart ) {
        // Render chart
        if (gridContainer.items.length > 0) {
            // Remove/Clear container objects ... if exists
            Ext.Array.each( gridContainer.items, function( aItm ) {
                switch( aItm.itemId ) {
                    case 'topbox':
                        break;

                    case 'buttonBox':
                        if ( aItm.items.length > 0 ) {
                            aItm.removeAll( true );
                        }
                        break;

                    case 'sliderBox':
                        if ( aItm.items.length > 0 ) {
                            aItm.removeAll( true );
                        }
                        break;

                    case 'chartbox':
                        if ( aItm.items.length > 0 ) {
                            aItm.removeAll();
                        }
                        break;
                }
            });
        }
        that.down('#chartbox').add(myChart);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect there's a rendering bug, because when i add this to my code (before defining the app), replacing the chart works:

```
Ext.override(Rally.ui.chart.Chart,{
    onRender: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        this._unmask();
    }
});
```